# SO内のページのURLを書くと、日本語部分が２回表示される。

Tags: バグ, 完了

次のようなURLを書くと、

```
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/97/好きなように回答-コメント-編集-投票してください
```

以下のように表示されます。

[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/97/好きなように回答-コメント-編集-投票してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/97/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86-%E6%8A%95%E7%A5%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

日本語部分が２回表示されているようです。

Answer (score 2):

> **更新：**この問題は解決出来ました。日本語にしても、`%e5%86`でも、ちゃんと写します。

現在開発者が解決方法を探しています。原因は日本語のブラウザみたいです。自分で当質問のURLをコピペすると下記になります：

```
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255/so%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AEurl%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E3%81%8C%EF%BC%92%E5%9B%9E%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B
```

上記は正しく表示されます：

> [SO内のページのURLを書くと、日本語部分が２回表示される。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255/so%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AEurl%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E3%81%8C%EF%BC%92%E5%9B%9E%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)

一部の日本ブラウザが下記のようにコピペされます：

```
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255/SO内のページのURLを書くと-日本語部分が２回表示される
```

上記をコピペすると正しく表示されません：

> [SO内のページのURLを書くと、日本語部分が２回表示される。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255/SO%E5%86%85%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AEURL%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E3%81%8C%EF%BC%92%E5%9B%9E%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)

複数の解決方法を試してきましたが、URLのパターンが多いため、思ったより複雑です。まだ進んでいますが、解決方法がまだ探せていない状況です。

Comment: この手のURLのすぐ後ろに文章を続ける場合、間に半角スペースをいれないと表示されない、ということですね。既存の投稿がこれに該当しないか、一括で確認する方法があれば（SEDE？）確認しておくといいかもしれません。